# 3d Polygon Plot in matplotlib baselines slanted

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create my own version of the 3D Polygon plot as shown on the Matplotlib web site:

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#polygon-plots

My version is here:

http://hastebin.com/laqekeceru.py

Example data:

http://hastebin.com/vocagogihu.coffee

Image output from two different view points is here:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the images, the baseline of the graphs steadily starts to slope up.

I tried the tutorial version and it worked fine, but it has significantly less data.

Is this a bug in matplotlib?
Is it my code?

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Python 2.6
- numpy==1.8.0
- matplotlib==1.3.1 (latest version)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your code **in the body of the question itself**. There is no guarantee that external sites will be available in the future.

Comment: Agreed to posting the code in the question - it's short enough to fit fine.  A quick look doesn't reveal anything odd that would cause this, though ... maybe others more expert can say

Comment: This maybe related to a bug that has been fixed in 1.4.0 (sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0rc2/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has just something to do with polygons and nothing specific to 3d.

Your PolyCollection is a collection of points forming a closed polygon. The "creeping" baseline is actually one side of the polygon, the implicit line from the last point to the first point of each polygon.

To illustrate this, please see:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

# some sample data
data = [(0,.5), (1,.7), (2,.3), (3,.6), (4,.2)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# draw the polygon
p = PolyCollection([data], facecolor=(1,0,0,.5), edgecolor='none')
ax.add_collection(p)

# draw the line
d = np.array(data)
ax.plot(*zip(*data), color='k', linewidth=2)
```

This simple example gives:

[image]

To fix this problem you will need to add zeros to the ends of the polygon:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

# some sample data
data = [(0,.5), (1,.7), (2,.3), (3,.6), (4,.2)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# draw the polygon
# pad the data:
data.insert(0, (data[0][0],0))
data.append((data[-1][0], 0))

p = PolyCollection([data], facecolor=(1,0,0,.5), edgecolor='none')
ax.add_collection(p)

# draw the line, note that the padded points are not drawn
d = np.array(data)
ax.plot(*zip(*data[1:-1]), color='k', linewidth=2)
```

Now the slanted line is away:

[image]

If you need to have the curve at the edge of the polygon, you will need to draw it separately (as the edge of the polygon is something you do not want to show).